# null results of search by _id in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting `[]` res in mongoose find by `{parentId: cat._id}`

```
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    slug: String,
    parentId: {type: ObjectId, required: false},
    ancestors: {
        type: [{
            _id: ObjectId,
            name: String,
            slug: String
        }], required: false
    }
});

CategorySchema.statics.getNested = function(parentSlug,cb){
    this.findOne({slug:parentSlug},function(err,cat){
        if (err) {
            cb(err);
        } else {
            this.find({parentId: cat._id},function(err, cats){
                console.log(cats);
                if (err){
                    cb(err);
                } else {
                    cb(null,cats);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I tried `{parentId: ObjectId(cat._id)}` but this did not work too `// ObjectId(cat._id) -> undefined`

How do I search mongoose by `_id`?

**UPDATE!**

The query

```
Category.find({parentId:'5634eeb38a33a59c1dffa6ee'}, function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

is working fine but how?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `{parentId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(cat._id)}`

Comment: No. this.find({parentId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(cat._id)},function(err, cats) dont work

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect ObjectId type in your schema, you should use Schema.Types.ObjectId instead of Schema.ObjectId because they return different values:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-objectid-js
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types-objectid-js

If you replace your ObjectId definition to the following

```
var ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;
```

your code should work correctly.

Comment: Can you please print your cat value after you do this.findOne({slug:parentSlug}) ?